# Tags not firing in HTML 'li' element with 'id' attribute?

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have written an Event Based rule in DTM. Below is the code where I am applying rule:

`

```
<li class="" id="204">Element 1</li>

<li class="" id="227">Element 2</li>

<li class="" id="135">Element 3</li>

<li class="" id="235">Element 4</li>

<li class="active" id="201">Element 5</li>
```

`

So, in the Event rule section, I have selected the Event type as 'click', Element Tag as 'LI', and then manually assigned properties & attributes as :
id = 201 (for "Element 5", in this case).

But the tag on the page is not firing, when I am clicking on 'Element 5' section. Not really sure, why.

This is basic most thing in DTM, but this is unexpectedly not working in my case.

Can someone please help.

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: Have you turned on debugging (_satellite.setDebug(true)) and made sure the click is getting registered? What's supposed to happen when you click the li?

Comment: @Brett: Yes, I debugged this, but this rule was not getting triggered on the click of any of the 'li' element.

Primarily, I just want to fire an on-click tag on the click of any of the 'li' element. For this, I have set condition as when id equals '201' (or whatever), the tag should fire.

Not sure, what am I missing. This is pretty straight forward, but still not working.


Let me know.


Thanks

Comment: What is your condition? In case you didn't know, the manually assign properties and attributes isn't a filter or condition. You would have to set that up in the custom code rule condition. Probably easier, add a class to the li elements and just add the click targeting to those with li.myClass

Comment: Right Brett, I tried this also, by writing a custom code and returning true if script matches the condition (as  `$(this).attr('id') == '<id-value>' ` ). But this was also not working.

Comment: Have you tried logging the id to the console and returning true in the custom code? Everything you've mentioned works for me with a test I setup. Tried removing the manually assigned properties to see if that was causing issue? Sorry if this isn't the answer but just trying to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes right, the custom script which I wrote do have 'true' condition in it, but not working.See the exact code:

First, I set the 'Element Tag or Selector' as 'li', then under the custom criteria, wrote this stuff: 
`if ( $(this).attr('id') == '204' )
{
_satellite.setVar("Value", 'onclick' );
return true;
}
else
return false; `
and then finally setting this in some eVar(or prop) under the next section, as: `eVar1="%Value%"`.

This is like really disappointing me. Such an easy stuff, not working for me. God knows, where I am going wrong.

Comment: I would try this: _satellite.notify($(this).attr('id'),1);return true; and see what happens. Perhaps the id is not populating correctly.

Comment: One question, '1' mentioned above is the id value or is this to set  this as true/false ? In this code, I am putting id value in place of '1'.

Comment: 1 is the priority value for the satellite notify function

Comment: how would DTM know, on which 'id', it has to fire tag ?
We are not providing any id value in this.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: It would fire for all but you could them confirm that you're getting the expected id and got from there.